# How to speed up a video in order to shorten its length and embed a timestamp to represent time as it was recorded?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video recorded at 5 fps that I want to speed up to 30 fps to shorten it. That is simple enough as:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 30 -vf "setpts=(1/6)*PTS" output.mp4
```

But when I try to add a timestamp to it with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 30 -vf "setpts=(1/6)*PTS, drawtext=text='%{pts\:localtime\:1610043985\:%Y\-%m\-%d %H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S.}%{eif\:mod(n,30)\:d}'" output.mp4
```

The timestamp does not longer represents the time as it was recorded (it should run faster now)

What would be the simplest way to achieve this on a single pass?

Comment: Why not add the timestamp first and then speed up the video?

Comment: Well... there are a lot of reasons, but mostly because I need to re-scale the shorter video so I would rather do a single re encoding of the original and have everything in a single pass. I didn't mention this before to keep the question simple, but also I believe that should be correct way to do it if it is possible.

Comment: I added an answer to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `drawtext` filter first and then the `setpts` filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 30 -vf "drawtext=..., setpts=..." output.mp4
```